# Error using Django-Hstore for PostgreSQL HSTORE in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, hstore, django-hstore

When I run my Django Server, I got this error:

```
    class HStoreDescriptor(models.fields.subclassing.Creator):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'subclassing'
```

I am using, the currently newest, Django 1.10, and django-hstore 1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be easily solved by downgrading Django to version 1.9. It seems the version 1.10 is not stable yet.

```
pip install Django==1.9
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use Django_Hstore extentions on 1.10.

Add 'django.contrib.postgres' in your INSTALLED_APPS.

If hstrone not enabled on Postgres , Run sql script: `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore`

On Model:
Add: `from django.contrib.postgres.fields import HStoreField`

Add Field: `data = HStoreField()`

[For More İnformation :](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield)

Comment: Thanks, this was also helpful for Django 1.11